# React Native кнопка через WebView

Tags: reactjs, native

что я делаю не так? мне нужна кнопка которая при клике переходит по ссылке, переход нужен только через WebView (не через браузер)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';


export default class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <WebView
          source={{ html: 'https://google.com' }}
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
      />
      <TouchableHighlight style={{alignItems: 'center'}} onPress={this.onPress}>
        <Text>Click Me</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте детали в Ваш вопрос: что именно происходит в Вашем коде и чего Вы ожидаете.

Comment: Чтобы отрендерить внутри `WebView` контент с указанного адреса - нужно у `WebView` в `source` указать не `html` а `uri`, если там указываете адрес, а не HTML разметку. Вот так: `source={{ uri: 'https://google.com' }}`

Comment: я хочу сделать кнопку, при нажатии должен произойти переход по ссылке, но переход должен произойти внутри приложения (не в браузере)

Answer (score 0):

```
Constructor(props) {
...
this.setState({uri: ''});
...


render() {
....
<WebView source={{uri: this.state.uri}}...
...
<<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> {this.setState({uri: "https://mysite.com"})}}...
```

что то в этом духе